# In 2 Thessalonians 1:8 what does Paul mean by "obey the gospel"?

Tags: history

**Does Anyone Know How to "Obey the Gospel?"**

Paul and Peter use a phrase, "obey the gospel".

I'm looking for *"how to obey the gospel or good-news"* because I believe the gospel or good news is the death, burial and resurrection of Christ (1 Co 15:1-4) which is a **historical event**. ***How does one obey a historical event?***

Paul writes: 2 Thessalonians 1:8

> giving vengeance in a fire of flame {i.e. in flaming fire} to those who do not know God and to those who are **not obeying* the good-news** of our Lord Jesus Christ,
>   [MLV. (n.d.). MODERN LITERAL TRANSLATION OF THE BIBLE (2 Th 1:8).](http://www.modernliteralversion.org/)

Peter writes:

> 1 Peter 4:17
>   Because the time for the judgment is to begin from the house of God, and if it begins first from us, what will be the end of those who are **disobedient to the good-news** of God?
>   MLV. (n.d.). MODERN LITERAL TRANSLATION OF THE BIBLE (1 Pe 4:17).

Here are some other verses on obedience:

> So the word of God spread. The number of disciples in Jerusalem increased rapidly, and a large number of priests became **obedient to the faith**. ACTS 6:7
>
> Through him and for his name’s sake, we received grace and apostleship to call people from among all the Gentiles to the obedience that comes from faith. 6 And you also are among those who are called to belong to Jesus Christ. Ro 1:5–6
>
> But thanks be to God that, though you used to be slaves to sin, you wholeheartedly obeyed the form of teaching to which you were entrusted. 18 You have been set free from sin and have become slaves to righteousness. Ro 6:17–18
>
> I will not venture to speak of anything except what Christ has accomplished through me in leading the Gentiles to obey God by what I have said and done— 19 by the power of signs and miracles, through the power of the Spirit. So from Jerusalem all the way around to Illyricum, I have fully proclaimed the gospel of Christ. Ro 15:18–19
>
> Everyone has heard about your [ROMAN] obedience, so I am full of joy over you; but I want you to be wise about what is good, and innocent about what is evil. Ro 16:19
>
> Now to him who is able to establish you by my gospel and the proclamation of Jesus Christ, according to the revelation of the mystery hidden for long ages past, 26 but now revealed and made known through the prophetic writings by the command of the eternal God, so that all nations might believe and obey him— 27 to the only wise God be glory forever through Jesus Christ! Amen. Ro 16:25–27
>
> The reason I wrote you was to see if you would stand the test and be obedient in everything. 2 Co 2:9).
>
> Because of the service by which you have proved yourselves, men will praise God for the obedience that accompanies your confession of the gospel of Christ, and for your generosity in sharing with them and with everyone else. 2 Co 9:12–13
>
> You were running a good race. Who cut in on you and kept you from obeying the truth?  Ga 5:7
>
> God is just: He will pay back trouble to those who trouble you 7 and give relief to you who are troubled, and to us as well. This will happen when the Lord Jesus is revealed from heaven in blazing fire with his powerful angels. 8 He will punish those who do not know God and do not obey the gospel of our Lord Jesus. 2 Th 1:6–8
>
> Therefore, my dear friends, as you have always obeyed—not only in my presence, but now much more in my absence—continue to work out your salvation with fear and trembling, 13 for it is God who works in you to will and to act according to his good purpose. Php 2:12–13
>
> Now that you have purified yourselves by obeying the truth so that you have sincere love for your brothers, love one another deeply, from the heart. 23 For you have been born again, not of perishable seed, but of imperishable, through the living and enduring word of God. 1 Pe 1:22–23

Comment: It seems to be the latter.  Voted to close on basis of "unclear what you're asking"

Comment: Does my question stand out better now? I was in a hurry at the time and just got the basics put in with an intent to edit it later. I just didn't want to forget it. As a newby, I'm sorry for the assumption. Won't happen again.

Answer (score 2):

The Gospel (εὐαγγέλιον - *evangelion*; lit. "good message") was, in fact, something that Jesus preached while He was on earth, and not some historical event.  This can be seen in the words of Jesus Himself - for example:

> Matthew 4:23
>
> *And Jesus went about all Galilee, teaching in their synagogues, and preaching the Gospel of the Kingdom, and healing all manner of sickness and all manner of disease among the people.*

The Gospel contains a number of commandments that followers of Jesus are to obey.  The Sermon on the Mount, for example, is a recapitulation of commandments from the Law of Moses expanded and amplified (*Ye have heard that it was said ... But I say unto you ...*; Matthew 5:21-22, etc.).

The admonition in 2 Thessalonians 1:8 is entirely consistent with what Jesus Himself said (Luke 6:46-49):

> *And why call ye me, Lord, Lord, and do not the things which I say? Whosoever cometh to me, and heareth my sayings, and doeth them, I will shew you to whom he is like: He is like a man which built an house, and digged deep, and laid the foundation on a rock: and when the flood arose, the stream beat vehemently upon that house, and could not shake it: for it was founded upon a rock. But he that heareth, and doeth not, is like a man that without a foundation built an house upon the earth; against which the stream did beat vehemently, and immediately it fell; and the ruin of that house was great.*

Comment: Nice and succint +1

Answer (score 0):

If you ask this question of 12 theologians you will almost certainly get at least 13 answers.  However, most surround the doctrine of the imitation of Christ which is very deeply embedded in the NT teaching.  I believe it is this that encompasses most other answers and enable the Christian to be obedient to history as you so aptly phrase it.

- Made like God.  Gen 1:26, 27, 9:6, Eph 4:20-24, 1 John 3:2.  Note that this means that one of the purposes of salvation is to restore the likeness of God in humans that sin has erased.
- Walk as Jesus walked.  1 John 2:6.
- Jesus was led by the Spirit Matt 4:1.  The Christian must be born of the Spirit (John 3:5) by receiving the gift of the Spirit (Acts 2:38) and walk by the Spirit (Gal 5:25, John 6:63, Phil 3:3, John 4:24).  In fact the whole life of Christian is to put aside the “psychical” mind and live by the Spirit (1 Cor 2:14, 1 Cor 15:44-46, Gal 5:17, Jude 19, John 6:63, 1 Peter 3:18).
- Love as Jesus loved.  John 13:34, 35, 15:12, 1 John 4:8, 11, 19, Eph 5:1, 2.
- Lay down life for friends.  John 15:13, Eph 5:2.
- Jesus’ suffering leaves us an example.  John 16:33, 2 Tim 1:4, Heb 13:12, 13, 1 Peter 2:21.
- Because Jesus was persecuted, so are His followers.  John 15:20, 21.
- Conformed to the likeness of the Son.  Rom 8:29.
- Transforming our will and bodies to conform to God’s will.  Rom 12:1, 2.
- Jesus was baptised (Matt 3:13-17, Mark 1:9-11, Luke 3:21, 22) and so should we be baptised, Matt 28:19, Acts 2:38, 10:48, 16:31, 22:16, Rom 6:1-9, etc.
- Forgive as Jesus forgave.  Matt 6:12, Eph 4:32.
- Be imitators of God.  Eph 5:1.
- Be holy as Jesus is holy.  Lev 11:44, 45, 1 Peter 1:15, 16.
- Be pure as He is pure.  1 John 3:3.
- Partakers of the divine nature.  2 Peter 1:4.
- We are being changed into Christ’s glory (= reputation).  2 Cor 3:18.
- Pray as Jesus prayed.  Luke 11:1.
- We are to have the mind of Christ.  Phil 2:5, 1 Cor 2:16.
- Be kind because God is kind.  Luke 6:34, 35.
- Be merciful because God is merciful.  Luke 6:36.
- Be servants to others as Jesus was.  John 13:15-17, 1 Peter 4:11b, Matt 20:24-28.
- Be patient as Jesus was patient.  1 Tim 1:16.
- Talk/speak as Jesus speaks.  1 Peter 4:11a.
- Be “perfect” (= mature and generous to enemies) as the Father is.  Matt 5:48.
- Husbands should love their wives as Christ loved His people and gave Himself for her.  Eph 5:25.
- Keep the commandments as Jesus kept the commandments.  John 15:10.
- Abide in Christ as Christ abides in us.  John 15:4.
- Jesus is the “beginning and the end” (Rev 22:13) and Jesus is the beginning and end of our faith (Heb 12:2).
- We are co-heirs with Christ of glory.  Rom 8:17.
- Jesus gave his all and we must give up all things for Him.  Rom 8:32.
- Jesus is called the “Lamb of God” (John 1:29, 1 Cor 5:7) and so are His followers (John 10:1-18, 21:15-17)
- Jesus washed the disciples’ feet (John 13:1-17) and so should we (John 13:14-17)
- Jesus is the light of the world (John 1:4, 9, 8:12, 9:5) and so are we (Matt 5:14-16)

The Bible strongly emphasises the imitation of Christ by the mechanism of beholding Christ (Phil 2:4, 5, Heb 12:2, 3, 1 Cor 2:16, Col 3:1-4, 2 Cor 3:18, Rom 13:14, John 17:17, Matt 6:19-33, 12:33-35, Rom 8:12-14; contrast 2 Kings 17:15, Ps 115:4-8, 135:15-18, Prov 10:24, 24:8, 9).  “Salvation is found in no one else, for there is no other name under heaven given among mankind by which we must be saved.” (Acts 4:12)  In fact, it is the imitation of Christ that gives Christians the title; “Christian” meaning, one who is like Christ.

Jesus told us that He was the way, the truth and the life. (John 14:6)  Therefore, to be "obedient o the truth" is to have faith in Jesus.

Comment: Excellent! Can we compare 1 Co 15:1-4 with Rom 6:3-5 as THE INITIAL form "obeying the gospel" must take? LOOK through verse 17, if not the whole chapter. So far, no one has noticed this. Thanks so much for a great answer!

Comment: Quite right!!  We died to the old life are raised to a new life in Christ - and that life is one of imitating Him as stated above.  The Gospel is the good tidings that makes atonement and obedience to a new life possible.  Hence it is good news.

Answer (score 0):

The word translated "obedience" in 2 Thessalonians 1:8 is ὑπακούω which does have "obey" as part of its semantic domain. That means, given the right context one might translate this word as "obey". However, the word has [other legitimate usages as outlined in a lexicon](http://logeion.uchicago.edu/%E1%BD%91%CF%80%CE%B1%CE%BA%CE%BF%CF%8D%CF%89).

Also, though the gospel is the **news of** an historical event (not the event itself) it also demands a response:

> Acts 17:30 And the times of this ignorance God winked at; **but now commandeth all men every where to repent:
>   Because he hath appointed a day, in the which he will judge the world in righteousness by that man whom he hath ordained**; whereof he hath given assurance unto all men, in that he hath raised him from the dead.

The sense of the word translated "obey" is similar to the English word "listen". Listening means hearing but implies acting on what you hear. "I listened to my lawyer" should mean that you kept your mouth shut, not just that you heard his voice giving advice. Translating as "those that don't listen to the gospel", with that understanding is basically what the word is saying.

The word "gospel" [originally referred to a reward given to the bearer of "good news"](https://www.blueletterbible.org/lang/lexicon/lexicon.cfm?Strongs=G2098&t=KJV) such as the birth of a royal baby or something:

> [KJV 2 Samuel 4:10](https://www.blueletterbible.org/kjv/2samuel/4/10/s_271010) When one told me, saying, Behold, Saul is dead, thinking to have brought good tidings, I took hold of him, and slew him in Ziklag, who thought that I would have given him a reward for his tidings:

Comment: Thank you for this answer. Your reply actually reaches into another question I have, which I will save for later. I wonder, however, what you think about whether or not we can compare 1 Co 15:1-4 with Rom 6:3-5 as THE INITIAL form "obeying the gospel" must take? LOOK through verse 17, if not the whole chapter.

Note, I just now found how to use bold which I'll use in the future. My caps were intended as emphasis and not shouting.

Comment: Don, please note that this site is not about "theology" (what form the gospel *should* take initially? We don't do "should") but rather about "hermeneutics". IE: This is not the site to work out "doctrine" per se. We focus on a verse or two, not on "big ideas". I'm not saying you're not doing that, just to clarify the site goals.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put on Christ, to be clothed with His righteousness, and to walk in The Way.  You are obedient to the good news - the gospel of Christ when you are baptized / immersed into His death, burial, and resurrection.

Acts 2:37-41,

> *"37 And having heard, they were pricked to the heart; they say also to Peter, and to the rest of the apostles, `What shall we do, men, brethren?'*
>
> *38 and Peter said unto them, `Reform, and be baptized each of you on the name of Jesus Christ, to remission of sins, and ye shall receive the gift of the Holy Spirit,*
>
> *39 for to you is the promise, and to your children, and to all those afar off, as many as the Lord our God shall call.'*
>
> *40 Also with many more other words he was testifying and exhorting, saying, `Be saved from this perverse generation;'*
>
> *41 then those, indeed, who did gladly receive his word were baptized, and there were added on that day, as it were, three thousand souls,"*  (YLT)

Be aware that the original meaning of the Anglicized word "baptized" is from the Greek "baptizo", Strong's Gr. 907, and means immersed.  (See [Biblehub](https://biblehub.com/greek/907.htm))

Also, be aware that the promise of the gift of the Holy Spirit was a promise to that generation (you and your children) for the confirmation of the word from God, so that the people could believe the apostles and disciples as they spread the good news.  Once that which was perfect / complete was come (1 Cor. 13:10), the completed record of the gospel, what we now call the New Testament, then the miraculous gifts of the Holy Spirit died out.

We have to answer the call, which was demonstrated by Paul's conversion.

Acts 9:17-18,

> *"17 And Ananias went away, and did enter into the house, and having put upon him [his] hands, said, `Saul, brother, the Lord hath sent me -- Jesus who did appear to thee in the way in which thou wast coming -- that thou mayest see again, and mayest be filled with the Holy Spirit.'*
>
> *18 And immediately there fell from his eyes as it were scales, he saw again also presently, and having risen, was baptized,"*  (YLT)

Saul / Paul answered the call by obeying the command to be baptized.

Matt. 22:11,

> *"11`And the king having come in to view those reclining, saw there a man not clothed with clothing of the marriage-feast,"*  (YLT)

Being clothed with the righteousness of Christ is to put on His righteousness through baptism into His sacrifice. See also 2 Cor. 5:3.

Gal 3:26-29,

> *"26 for ye are all sons of God through the faith in Christ Jesus,*
>
> *27 for as many as to Christ were baptized did put on Christ;*
>
> *28 there is not here Jew or Greek, there is not here servant nor freeman, there is not here male and female, for all ye are one in Christ Jesus;*
>
> *29 and if ye [are] of Christ then of Abraham ye are seed, and according to promise -- heirs."*  (YLT)

Those who have heard and believe the gospel are immersed for forgiveness of sins.

Mark 16:16,

> *"he who hath believed, and hath been baptized, shall be saved; and he who hath not believed, shall be condemned."*  (*YLT)

Once baptized the command is to continue to believe, to grow in the knowledge of the Lord, and to walk after Him.  All of the letters to the "ecclesia" or the assemblies were written to those who had obeyed that command, to those who had already been baptized.  That is why the letters are addressed "to the assembly of God that is in Corinth, to those sanctified in Christ Jesus, called saints," (1. Cor. 1:2), or "to the saints who are in Ephesus," (Eph 1:1).

They were told to continue to believe, to keep faith, and to walk in The Way.  That is the obedience to the gospel, first to answer the call to be baptized, and then to walk with Him.

Comment: Thank you! I still don't have enough reputation points to "like" your post.